# Why is $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x} dx = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x} dx = +\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I have the theoretical proof but I can't visualise it, doesn't it mean that the area under the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is infinite?[image]

How is it possible since it tends towards 0?

Comment: It literally says that the are under the curve $\frac{1}{x}$ measured from $1$ to infinity is infinite. Also the area under the curve $\frac{1}{x}$ measured on the interval $(0,1]$ is infinite.

It shouldn't be weird that even though $\frac{1}{x}$ converges to 0, the area need not. Consider the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$. Clearly, this converges to 0 when $n$ gets large. But $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots +\frac{1}{n}$ tends to infinity. This is a very similar phenomenon.

Comment: I got that, but how is it possible that a curve that tends towards 0 has an infinite area? 
Why is it different for $\frac{1}{x^2}$ for instance? (again, I get the theoretical concept that the indefinite integral $\frac{2}{x}$ tends to 0 as x tends to infinity, but can't really grasp why)

Comment: the curve doesn't approach 0 fast enough, hence the area under it is also unbounded.

Comment: It is not possible to actually "grasp" an area with infinite width, with intuition and visualization only.

Comment: I think you're perhaps reading slightly too far into it - at this stage there isn't really a deep reason that certain sequences converge and others don't, it's just something you have to get used to.

Comment: I'll be vivid: $1/x$ goes to zero. $1/x^2$ gets slammed down to zero. $1/x^3$ gets SLAMMED down to zero... $1/e^x$ gets *obliterated* ... and $1/n!$ doesn't get a chance to say hello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely correct in saying that the area under the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is infinite. And yes, while the function tends to zero, it doesn't tend to zero "fast enough" for the area to converge. One possibly more intuitive way to see this is to consider the lower Riemann sum with width one. The sum of these areas is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} + \dots$, which diverges, and since this area is less than the area of the integral, the integral must also diverge.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a feature of infinity that you have to get used to - some sequences tend to zero too slowly for their sum (or integral) to converge. The harmonic series is a classic example of this (and in fact provides a lower bound for your integral).

Notice that the classical paradox (cf Zeno) is that infinite series shouldn't converge at all - why would you expect that adding infinitely many (admittedly, quite small) numbers should always converge?

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x\mapsto at$, we get that for any $a\gt0$
$$
\int_a^{2a}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^2\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
Furthermore, since $\frac1t\ge\frac12$ on $[1,2]$, we get
$$
\int_1^2\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t\ge\frac12
$$
Therefore, breaking $(0,1]$ into intervals $\left(2^{-k-1},2^{-k}\right]$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{2^{-k-1}}^{2^{-k}}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_1^2\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\ge\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac12\\[6pt]
&=\infty
\end{align}
$$
For the second integral, substitute, $x\mapsto\frac1t$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^0t\,\mathrm{d}\frac1t\\
&=\int_1^0t\left(-\frac1{t^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\int_1^0\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t\\[9pt]
&=\infty
\end{align}
$$